# Mapping Cityname to GeoPoint from Logstash to Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack

I got some log like:

```
2015-09-25 12:07:55.441 INFO 17328 --- [][][][] 
XXX.YYY.SomeClass : Someone request in CityX!
```

And I import it to `Elasticsearch`:

```
{
    "_index": "logstash-2015.09.25",
    "_type": "redis-input",
    "_id": "AVADGRo7JaVbcBhehzEj",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
        "@timestamp": "2015-09-25T12:21:24.616+08:00",
        "@version": 1,
        "message": "Someone request in CityX!",
        "logger_name": "XXX.YYY.SomeClass",
        "thread_name": "pool-22-thread-1",
        "level": "INFO",
        "level_value": 20000,
        "HOSTNAME": "host",
        "host": "192.168.5.194: 57154",
        "type": "redis-input"
    }
}
```

I just want to map `CityX`(Any City Occurs in my Log, and assume we can get the latitude and longitude of every city) to `GeoPoint` in `Elasticsearch`, so that we can display the count of user request in map by `Kibana`. How should I do that?

Whole pipeline:

```
logstash(:4560) --> redis(:6379) --> logstash-indexer --> elasticsearch (:9200)
```

Config:

Logstash -> Redis:

```
input {
  tcp {
    port => 4560
    codec => json_lines
  }
}

output {

  redis {
    host => "10.0.40.155"
    port => 6379
    data_type => "list"
    key => "key_count"
  }
}
```

Redis -> Logstash -> Elasticsearch:

```
input {
  redis {
    host => "127.0.0.1"
    port => 6379
    type => "redis-input"
    data_type => "list"
    key => "key_count"
  }
}

output {
  stdout {}
  elasticsearch {
    host => "10.0.40.156"
    cluster => "elasticsearch"
    codec => "json"
    protocol => "http"
  }
}
```

Comment: Does you message field always contain a string similar to `Someone request in CityX!` just with different cities? Do you already have a list of geo-points for all the cities or you expect this to be dynamic?

Comment: Also as you properly know city names on earth are not unique (i.e. there are many cities called `San Francisco` in Manilla, too). So another question is how do you want to deal with that? Do you have a pre-defined list of cities that you know will appear in your logs? How is that log constructed, i.e. where does the city name (e.g. `CityX` in your example) come from?

Comment: @Val Thanks for your kind advice. We get the City from the telephone number from our user(In Chinese, there exists: `f(telephone number)=city`). We have a database of (phone number -> city), and we can buy another database of (city -> lat,long). I solved my problem by a simple grok filter. I will appreciate your any comment for my solution.

Comment: Of course if you have that (city -> lat,lon) database, you're problem is now much easier to solve. Glad you figured it out ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My Java program logs `City,Longitude,Latitude`:

My logs example:

```
ChinaUnicom Zhejiang Hangzhou 30.29294,120.10956 REQUEST
ChinaUnicom Zhejiang Hangzhou 30.29294,120.10956 REQUEST
ChinaTelecom Zhejiang Hangzhou 30.29294,120.10956 REQUEST
```

`Zhejiang` is a province of China, and `Hangzhou` is a city of `Zhejiang`.

I add a `grok` filter to parse the log first, then use `add_field` to transform it to geo_point which `Kibana` can recognise.

```
input {
  redis {
    host => "127.0.0.1"
    port => 6379
    type => "redis-input"
    data_type => "list"
    key => "key_count"
  }
}

filter {
  grok {
    match => { "message" => "%{WORD:carrier} %{WORD:province} %{WORD:city} %{BASE10NUM:latitude},%{BASE10NUM:longitude} %{WORD:geo_message}"}
    add_field => {"geoip.location" => "%{latitude},%{longitude}"}
  }
}

output {
  stdout {}
  elasticsearch {
    host => "10.0.40.156"
    cluster => "elasticsearch"
    codec => "json"
    protocol => "http"
  }
}
```

Comment: Cool, though, make sure that your mapping type defines `geoip.location` as a `geo_point` **before** you start indexing your logs.

Comment: @Val I didn't add any extra config to my `elasticsearch`, but it recognise my `geoip.location` as `geo_point`. But in the official document about `logstash`, they do it in the same way.

Comment: That's ok, I was just making sure you had geo_points to chew on ;-)